# Reassigning timestamps, watermarks in Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink

Consider I do this:

```
DataStream<POJO> ds = ...
ds.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(CustomAssigner)
.windowAll(...)
.apply(someFunction) //THIS FUNCTION CHANGES THE TIMESTAMP FIELD IN THE EVENTS
.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(AnotherCustomAssigner)
```

Is this valid? I don't know if watermarks/timestamps are global or just retained within a datastream?

**Edit**

```
class POJO{
   int timestamp;
   String someDetail; //key by this
   ...
}
```

DataStream ds = ....

```
ds.assignTimeStampsAndWatermarks(new AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks(){
   long maxTS = Long.MIN_VALUE;
   Watermarks checkAndGetNextWater(POJO, p, long l){
  maxTS = max(...)
  return new Watermarks(maxTS);
}

long ExtractTS(POJO p, long l){
  maxTS = max(...)
  return p.timeStamp;
}


  }).keyBy(someDetail property)
     .window(TumblingWindow(1 min))
      .apply(new AllWindowFunction<POJO, POJO, String, TimeWindow>(){
  public void apply(...){
    POJO newPOJO = ...;
    for(POJO it : iterable){
      newPOJO.timeStamp += ...
    }
    collector.collect(newPOJO);
  }
})
```

Now I am wondering

If I should assign timestamps again because I want to do `windowAll` and then `apply` again.

```
assignTimestamp...
.windowAll(..)
.apply(some other allwindow function)
```

Comment: Can someone explain what object reuse is? And should I be using `apply` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You are not expected to call assignTimestampsAndWatermarks again. Flink will ignore the timestamps in the POJOs created by the WindowFunction, and will timestamp the stream records wrapping those events with timestamps derived from the time at the end of that window. Normally this works just fine, though the follow-on window needs to cover a timeframe that's an integer multiple of the first.

If you are trying to construct a brand new stream that should be re-timestamped and have its own new watermarks, it might work to call assignTimestampsAndWatermarks again.

Comment: The `.apply(someFunction)` modifies the timestamps of the events coming in from the window. For example, in my window I might have events with timestamps `12, 13, 14, 52, 19` and the the aggregated object the `.apply(someFunction)` returns will have a timestamp of `12`, how will Flink handle this later on if the state/object/timestamp has been modified? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? I want to see if you are using TimeWindows or some other type, how the WindowFunction is constructing the objects it collects, whether you've enabled object reuse, and other details.